# Does an Apple warranty cover accidental damage?

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought an Apple MacBook Air and got a small dent on one corner.
Is it covered by Apple's one year warranty.

Comment: @bret7600 et al.  This is very much *on topic* as the question is narrow enough in scope to get an accurate, non opinionated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Warranties cover manufacturing defects or breakdowns, not damage.

For that you need insurance.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Terms and Conditions of AppleCare](https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/appmacnaen.html) support plans specific to the Mac, AppleTV, and the Apple Display, Section 4 subsection  (ii):

> #### 4.  What is not Covered?
>
> 4.1 Hardware Service. The Plan does not apply to:
>
> ...
>
> (ii) Damage caused by (a) a product that is not the Covered Equipment
> (b) **accident, abuse, misuse, liquid contact, fire, earthquake or other
> external cause,** (c) operating the Covered Equipment outside the
> permitted or intended uses described by the manufacturer, or (d)
> service (including upgrades and expansions) performed by anyone who is
> not a representative of Apple or an Apple Authorized Service Provider
> (“AASP”);

(emphasis mine)

You need 3rd party insurance.  I have used [Safeware](http://www.safeware.com/) in the past, but there are other options like [SquareTrade](https://www.squaretrade.com/)